# Divergence of a radial vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, differentiation, vector-fields

I'm reading an introduction to the Maxwell Equations. The author states that $\textbf E=\frac{e\textbf r}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$ (r is the magnitude of $\textbf r$). Then he derives the Gaussian law from that by using that $\nabla \cdot \textbf r=3$ and $\nabla r = \frac {\textbf r}{r}$. Why is that the case? I don't quite get how to arrive at the divergence and gradient of ${\textbf r}$ and $r$. Could somebody explain this to me?

Comment: $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{\hat{x}}x + \mathbf{\hat{y}}y + \mathbf{\hat{z}}z$, $\nabla = \mathbf{\hat{x}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \mathbf{\hat{y}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \mathbf{\hat{z}} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, $r=\sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. That's all you need to work it out.

Comment: @led23head Oh thanks, that's really simple. That was really a dumb question haha